# Can't resolve all parameters for TextEditorComponent: (?, ?)

Tags: javascript, angular

i try to do third party text-editor using ckeditor . but i am getting this error.

> compiler.js:432 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   TextEditorComponent: (?, ?). at syntaxError (compiler.js:432) at
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:12974)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:12845) at
>   CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:12428) at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:12287) at _filterJitIdentifiers.forEach
>   (compiler.js:28183) at Array.forEach () at
>   _filterJitIdentifiers.forEach (compiler.js:28182) at Array.forEach () at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:28179)

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChangeEvent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/editor';
import EditorUIView from '@ckeditor/ck`enter code here`editor5-ui/src/editorui/editoruiview';
import FocusTracker from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/focustracker';
import ComponentFactory from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/componentfactory';
import InlineEditableUIView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/editableui/inline/inlineeditableuiview';
import HtmlDataProcessor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/dataprocessor/htmldataprocessor';
import ElementReplacer from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/elementreplacer';

// Interfaces to extend the basic Editor API.
import DataApiMixin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/utils/dataapimixin';
import ElementApiMixin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/utils/elementapimixin';

// Helper function for adding interfaces to the Editor class.
import mix from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/mix';

// Helper function that gets the data from an HTML element that the Editor is attached to.
import getDataFromElement from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/dom/getdatafromelement';

// Helper function that binds the editor with an HTMLForm element.
import attachToForm from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/utils/attachtoform';

// Basic features that every editor should enable.
import Clipboard from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/clipboard';
import Enter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/src/enter';
import Typing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/typing';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import UndoEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/src/undo';

// Basic features associated with the edited content.
import BoldEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold/boldediting';
import ItalicEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic/italicediting';
import UnderlineEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline/underlineediting';
import HeadingEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/headingediting';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'dew-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-editor.component.scss']
})
export class TextEditorComponent extends Editor {
  sourceElement: any;
  data: any;
  model: any;
  ui: BootstrapEditorUI;
  _elementReplacer: any;
    constructor( element, config ) {
        super( config );

        // Remember the element the editor is created with.
        this.sourceElement = element;

        // Use the HTML data processor in this editor.
        this.data.processor = new HtmlDataProcessor();

        // Create the ("main") root element of the model tree.
        this.model.document.createRoot();

        // The UI layer of the editor.
        this.ui = new BootstrapEditorUI( this );

        // When editor#element is a textarea inside a form element,
        // the content of this textarea will be updated on form submit.
        attachToForm( this );

        // A helper to easily replace the editor#element with editor.editable#element.
        this._elementReplacer = new ElementReplacer();
    }

    get element() {
        return this.ui.view.element;
    }

    destroy() {
        // ...and restores the original editor#element...
        this._elementReplacer.restore();

        // ...and destroys the UI.
        this.ui.destroy();

        return super.destroy();
    }

    static create( element, config ) {
        return new Promise( resolve => {
            const editor = new this( element, config );
            const editable = editor.ui.view.editable;

            resolve(
                editor['initPlugins()']
                    .then( () => {
                        // Initialize the UI first. See the BootstrapEditorUI class to learn more.
                        editor.ui.init();

                        // Replace the editor#element with editor.editable#element.
                        editor._elementReplacer.replace( element, editable.element );

                        // Tell the world that the UI of the editor is ready to use.
                        editor[`fire( 'uiReady' )`];
                    } )
                    // Bind the editor editing layer to the editable in the DOM.
                    .then( () => editor['editing'].view.attachDomRoot( editable.element ) )
                    // Fill the editable with the intial data.
                    .then( () => editor.data.init( getDataFromElement( element ) ) )
                    // Fire the events that announce that the editor is complete and ready to use.
                    .then( () => {
                        editor[`fire( 'dataReady' )`];
                        editor[`fire( 'ready' )`];
                    } )
                    .then( () => Editor )
            );
        } );
    }

}


// Mixing interfaces, which extends the basic editor API.
mix( TextEditorComponent, DataApiMixin );
mix( TextEditorComponent, ElementApiMixin );




class BootstrapEditorUI {
  editor: any;
  view: any;
  componentFactory: any;
  focusTracker: any;
  constructor( editor ) {
      this.editor = editor;

      // The global UI view of the editor. It aggregates various Bootstrap DOM elements.
      const view = this.view = new EditorUIView( editor.locale );

      // This is the main editor element in the DOM.
      view.element = $( '.ck-editor' );

      // This is the editable view in the DOM. It will replace the data container in the DOM.
      view.editable = new InlineEditableUIView( editor.locale );

      // References to the dropdown elements for further usage. See #_setupBootstrapHeadingDropdown.
      view.dropdownMenu = view.element.find( '.dropdown-menu' );
      view.dropdownToggle = view.element.find( '.dropdown-toggle' );

      // References to the toolbar buttons for further usage. See #_setupBootstrapToolbarButtons.
      view.toolbarButtons = {};

      [ 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'undo', 'redo' ].forEach( name => {
          // Retrieve the jQuery object corresponding with the button in the DOM.
          view.toolbarButtons[ name ] = view.element.find( `#${ name }` );
      } );

      // Mandatory EditorUI interface components.
      this.componentFactory = new ComponentFactory( editor );
      this.focusTracker = new FocusTracker();
  }

  init() {
      const editor = this.editor;
      const view = this.view;

      // Render the editable component in the DOM first.
      view.editable.render();

      // Create an editing root in the editing layer. It will correspond with the
      // document root created in the constructor().
      const editingRoot = editor.editing.view.document.getRoot();

      // Bind the basic attributes of the editable in the DOM with the editing layer.
      view.editable.bind( 'isReadOnly' ).to( editingRoot );
      view.editable.bind( 'isFocused' ).to( editor.editing.view.document );
      view.editable.name = editingRoot.rootName;

      // // Setup the existing, external Bootstrap UI so it works with the rest of the editor.
      this._setupBootstrapToolbarButtons();
      this._setupBootstrapHeadingDropdown();
  }

  destroy() {
      this.view.editable.destroy();
  }

  // This method activates Bold, Italic, Underline, Undo and Redo buttons in the toolbar.
  _setupBootstrapToolbarButtons() {
    const editor = this.editor;

    for ( const name in this.view.toolbarButtons ) {
        // Retrieve the editor command corresponding with the ID of the button in the DOM.
        const command = editor.commands.get( name );
        const button = this.view.toolbarButtons[ name ];

        // Clicking the buttons should execute the editor command...
        button.click( () => editor.execute( name ) );

        // ...but it should not steal the focus so the editing is uninterrupted.
        button.mousedown( evt => evt.preventDefault() );

        const onValueChange = () => {
            button.toggleClass( 'active', command.value );
        };

        const onIsEnabledChange = () => {
            button.attr( 'disabled', () => !command.isEnabled );
        };

        // Commands can become disabled, e.g. when the editor is read-only.
        // Make sure the buttons reflect this state change.
        command.on( 'change:isEnabled', onIsEnabledChange );
        onIsEnabledChange();

        // Bold, Italic and Underline commands have a value that changes
        // when the selection starts in an element the command creates.
        // The button should indicate that e.g. you are editing text which is already bold.
        if ( !new Set( [ 'undo', 'redo' ] ).has( name ) ) {
            command.on( 'change:value', onValueChange );
            onValueChange();
        }
    }
}
_setupBootstrapHeadingDropdown() {
  const editor = this.editor;
  const dropdownMenu = this.view.dropdownMenu;
  const dropdownToggle = this.view.dropdownToggle;

  // Retrieve the editor commands for heading and paragraph.
  const headingCommand = editor.commands.get( 'heading' );
  const paragraphCommand = editor.commands.get( 'paragraph' );

  // Create a dropdown menu entry for each heading configuration option.
  editor.config.get( 'heading.options' ).map( option => {
      // Check if options is a paragraph or a heading as their commands differ slightly.
      const isParagraph = option.model === 'paragraph';

      // Create the menu item DOM element.
      const menuItem = $(
          `<a href="#" class="dropdown-item heading-item_${ option.model }">` +
              `${ option.title }` +
          '</a>'
      );

      // Upon click, the dropdown menu item should execute the command and focus
      // the editing view to keep the editing process uninterrupted.
      menuItem.click( () => {
          const commandName = isParagraph ? 'paragraph' : 'heading';
          const commandValue = isParagraph ? undefined : { value: option.model };

          editor.execute( commandName, commandValue );
          editor.editing.view.focus();
      } );

      dropdownMenu.append( menuItem );

      const command = isParagraph ? paragraphCommand : headingCommand;

      // Make sure the dropdown and its items reflect the state of the
      // currently active command.
      const onValueChange = isParagraph ? onValueChangeParagraph : onValueChangeHeading;
      command.on( 'change:value', onValueChange );
      onValueChange();

      // Heading commands can become disabled, e.g. when the editor is read-only.
      // Make sure the UI reflects this state change.
      command.on( 'change:isEnabled', onIsEnabledChange );

      onIsEnabledChange();

      function onValueChangeHeading() {
          const isActive = !isParagraph && command.value === option.model;

          if ( isActive ) {
              dropdownToggle.children( ':first' ).text( option.title );
          }

          menuItem.toggleClass( 'active', isActive );
      }

      function onValueChangeParagraph() {
          if ( command.value ) {
              dropdownToggle.children( ':first' ).text( option.title );
          }

          menuItem.toggleClass( 'active', command.value );
      }

      function onIsEnabledChange() {
          dropdownToggle.attr( 'disabled', () => !command.isEnabled );
      }
  } );
}
}
TextEditorComponent
    .create( $( '#editor' ).get( 0 ), {
        plugins: [
            Clipboard, Enter, Typing, Paragraph,
            BoldEditing, ItalicEditing, UnderlineEditing, HeadingEditing, UndoEditing
        ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        window['editor'] = editor;
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
let config = {
            plugins: [
                Clipboard, Enter, Typing, Paragraph,
                BoldEditing, ItalicEditing, UnderlineEditing, HeadingEditing, UndoEditing
            ]
        };
```

Comment: Can you create a replica of your code on stackblitz?

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd8ihy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i create stackblidz link

Comment: On your stackblitz, it's still having errors. I think ckeditor won't work on stackblitz. I went through a basic setup from https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#quick-start and created a project on https://github.com/shhdharmen/app-ckeditor. It's working fine.